# Why `git diff` do not hide renames?

Tags: git, git-diff

I applied commit, which renames filenames on both branches (eg. did same change on both branches), then compare these branches via `git diff --stat branch1...branch2`

Why these renamed files are displayed as changed?

```
 .../all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo1.bin          | Bin
 .../all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo2.bin          | Bin
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/README     |   0
 conf/rabbitmq.conf                                        |   2 +
 ...
 49 files changed, 1251 insertions(+), 425 deletions(-)
```

I expect that it should not be shown, because there is no changes between these files.

**UPD**
More info on commits:

```
$ git show --stat d1a22c7289
commit d1a22c72894cd7365a1a79a610334ac01527e6d5
Author: Eugen Konkov <Eugen.Konkov@xxx>
Date:   Fri Aug 19 15:21:25 2022 +0200

    This configuration file is not used on production servers. Thus disabled.

 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo1.bin     | Bin
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo2.bin     | Bin
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/README            |   0
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/configuration.xml |   0
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/extendedpolicy    |   0
 5 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)


$ git show --stat 9477bd04a1
commit 9477bd04a13468be57d1da8919be8823efac3356
Author: Eugen Konkov <Eugen.Konkov@xxx>
Date:   Fri Aug 19 15:21:25 2022 +0200

    This configuration file is not used on production servers. Thus disabled.

 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo1.bin     | Bin
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/CardInfo2.bin     | Bin
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/README            |   0
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/configuration.xml |   0
 conf/production/all/{datacash => datacash-old}/extendedpolicy    |   0
 5 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Left-right comparison of branches shows this (notice `=`):

[image]

[image]

*too much changes on branches, can not copy/paste them as is

Comment: Well, there *is* a change, and quite a significant one - the file was moved. That seems like a useful piece of information to me.

Comment: I'd pull my hair out if `git diff --stat` didn't show the renames like that!

Comment: The *file* did not change, but the *treeish* object that refers to the file did. That's the change being reported.

Comment: @IMSoP But the OP claims the _same_ move was made on _both_ branches being diffed. So the diff should be empty in this regard. If the claim is correct. Big "if" of course.

Comment: @matt Hm, I see why you say that, although the question isn't very clear - it might just mean "both branches include renames", rather than "both branches include _the exact same_ renames". I just tested that a very simple scenario with renaming the same file on two different branches, and it shows no difference between them, as expected.

Comment: @joanis: Probably I forget to put `...`. Sorry. Question was fixed.

Comment: @IMSoP, similar changes are done on both branches, so diff should not show them.

Comment: `git diff A...B` does not compare revisions `A` and `B`, but compares the merge base of `A` and `B` to `B`.

Comment: @matt, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about renames, but a misunderstanding of what the `...` syntax means in `git diff`. Here's [how the git manual currently describes it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203):

> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second `<commit>`, starting at a common ancestor of both `<commit>`. `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.

To put it a different way, it finds the commits which are "on branch B, but not also on branch A". Crucially, it is determining which *commits* to show, not which *changes* to show.

Consider you have the following commit graph:

```
* 222eee  (branch-2) rename foo to bar
| * 111fff  (branch-1) rename foo to bar
|/
* aa99bb some existing point in history
```

Running `git merge-base branch-1 branch-2` will give you `aa99bb`: the last common ancestor of the two branches.

Running `git diff branch-1...branch-2` will then compare *that* to `222eee`, which is the tip of `branch-2`.

So the result is a diff showing *only* the changes in commit `222eee`. The changes in `111fff` are never even looked up.

Comment: That is strange that `111fff` is never looked up. If so the we can do `git diff aa99bb...222eee`. Why we provide `111fff` then?

Comment: @EugenKonkov Because you might not know what the "merge base" of the two branches is. In this simple example, `aa99bb` is easy to spot by eye, but there might be hundreds of other commits in the graph. So "find me where these two branches diverged" is a useful thing to ask git to do. Perhaps "branch-1" is a release with some hotfixes, and "branch-2" is the current mainline of development; so `git diff branch-1...branch-2` is the changes that have been developed since the release was made (regardless of the content of the hotfixes).

Comment: Thinking about it, the `(master)` in my example was probably a distraction: most likely, there will be no branch or tag pointing at `aa99bb`, it's just an arbitrary point in history which is reachable from both branches.

Comment: > `git diff branch-1...branch-2 is the changes that have been developed since the release was made`. So if on either branches are same changes, they should not be shown.

Comment: @EugenKonkov That's why I said "regardless of the content of the hotfixes" in that comment, and "Crucially, it is determining which commits to show, not which changes to show" in the answer. I'm not really sure what more you're expecting to get out of this conversation; that's what the `...` syntax means, and if that's not what you want, don't use it.

Comment: Seems GH have same issue. When I do PR, I want to see which changes are introduced by this PR and do not want to see changes which `cherry-picked` from master branch. Probably there should be some option to `diff` that allows to ignore those cherry-picked commits. I really not eager to messup with already introduced changes.

Comment: Probably I need to ask question differently: how to see changes introduced on branch-1 and ignore similar changes. What do you think?